# Cannot set the value for radiobutton

Tags: java, html, spring

I have the next `.html` file:

```
<body>

<form action="/add" method="post" class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey w3-text-blue w3-margin" style="width: 50%">
    <h2 class="w3-center">Contact Us</h2>

    <div class="w3-row w3-section">
        <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-barcode"></i></div>
        <div class="w3-rest">
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="passportNumber" type="text" placeholder="Passport Data">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-row w3-section">
        <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-male fa"></i></div>
        <div class="w3-rest">
            <input class="w3-radio" name="gender" type="radio" value="1" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-row w3-section">
        <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-female"></i></div>
        <div class="w3-rest">
            <input class="w3-radio" name="gender" type="radio" value="2" required>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="w3-container w3-margin">
        <input class="w3-button w3-blue" type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
```

In this file I set `gender` `value = "1"/"2"'
but when I submit the form and hit into controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView savePerson(
        @RequestParam String gender
){
    System.out.println(gender);
    return null;
}
```

I always get the `gender` value = "on"

How to correctly set the value in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the missing link here is the omission of an id attribute for your radio buttons. Try to add a unique id and see if that fixes the issue. Example below:

```
<input class="w3-radio" name="gender" type="radio" id="male" value="male" required>
<input class="w3-radio" name="gender" type="radio" id="female" value="female" required>
```

:) Hope this helps lead you in the right direction.
-Matthew